# Differences between local and remote servers

Tags: php, ovh

I am developing a website with [Lumen framework](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2).

Everything is configured and works perfectly locally. However, this is not the case on the remote server.

Examples:

- When I recover a data from my database, even if the column contains only integers, the result in local is `integer`, but in remote : `string`. I have to specify `(int)` before the integer values to be sure they are integer.
- Locally, all my classes belong to namespaces. Everything works locally and in remote, sometimes I find myself with `Class 'blabla\blibli' not found`

Locally, I use Xampp (PHP Version 5.6.14, MySQL version 5.0.11-dev) and remove, I am on a shared server OVH (PHP Version 5.6.15, MySQL version 5.1.73).

Have you ever been confronted with that? Is there a way to fix this? May be a configuration file to write?

**EDIT** : Given the comments below, it seems that the answers to my questions actually depends on **the operating system use**.

Locally, I am working on a Windows machine, while in remote, it is a machine running Linux. Windows seems less of a hassle with certain rules, such as case sensitive.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but your include paths are set properly in PHP and your table structures are exactly the same in MySQL right?

Comment: @mikealeonetti everything is same in local and remote, including sql tables

Comment: I think windows os treated path in case insensitive matter,  and others,  is case sensitive matter but i could be wrong.  anyways i think its good pratice to have a unified naming convention.

Comment: @Andrew You are right, I didn't remember WIndows is not case sensitive. And like OVH runs on Linux, it is. Very good. Thanks

Comment: @Zl3n I believe your first problem is also caused by Windows/ Linux difference. Usually the DB driver is responsible for taking care of data types  of values in query results.

Comment: @Andrew You should post it as answer.

Comment: If PHP isn't compiled with `mysqlnd` (MySQL Native Driver) then PHP doesn't know how to interpret results of a query. The safest thing it can do is represent the results as string. You can find more about `mysqlnd` at [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqlnd.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I recover a data from my database, even if the column contains
>   only integers, the result in local is integer, but in remote : string.
>   I have to specify (int) before the integer values to be sure they are
>   integer.

This happens because PHP doesn't know how to interpret the query result. There is no information on how to interpret column values. To fix  that and to have correct type representation in PHP, you must have MySQL Native Driver installed (`mysqlnd`).

[Here's a link to documentation page that explains how to do it](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqlnd.php).

> Locally, all my classes belong to namespaces. Everything works locally
>   and in remote, sometimes I find myself with Class 'blabla\blibli' not
>   found

As per comments, it appears you're developing on one OS and deploying on another OS. Since Windows are actually **MUCH MUCH WORSE** than Linux (and this isn't me being a fan of Linux, it's a simple fact), they tend to forgive a lot when it comes to case sensitivity and what not.

Windows being forgiving for such things doesn't mean they're better or that there's less hassle with Windows (from a sys admin POV, Windows are a nightmare). It just means that you can't be lazy and expect OS to forgive everything and guess how you intended your code to work.

- Be consistent
- Set your development environment to match your deployment environment. You can use virtual machines for that. If you prefer developing under Windows, you can use Oracle Virtualbox to run a Linux OS, set up Samba and in Windows you can map a Linux drive. That lets you run your IDE under Windows, and all the code is saved to Linux box. Your web server and php should run under Linux and you can access it via your browser that runs under Windows
- Set up tests. Run them before you deploy. That will tell you whether you might have missed or omitted something
- Be consistent

Good luck.

Comment: Apparently, `mysqlnd` isn't and won't be built in at OVH. Why ? Good question. However, I noticed (by making a `phpinfo()`), that this option is integrated into my developement environment.


Using the framework Laravel (lumen), I had the opportunity to work with a homestead on Linux, but I'm more comfortable developing under windows. I have my habits and tools for many years. But in fact, I understand better now why there are so many differences between my local and remote environment. A simple question of operating system.


Thank you for this **very very clear explanation** !

Comment: I know *exactly* how you feel. I've been doing work under Windows for years and I made the transition to Linux slowly. Nowadays I use both operating systems, simply because one can't afford not to know what's happening in world of IT. Luckily, I am using both of them at the same time (I run my IDE @ windows, but the rest is under Linux VMs). The worst thing you can do to yourself is to have, like my friend says, a "stone brain". Expand your knowledge and horizons, try these new things, and trust me - your development life will become easier. You will at least know something others use.